# Join two Jquery .on functions

Tags: jquery, events, join

I have following code:

```
$("body").on("click", ".topic-name-edit.close", function (event) {
    var topicId = $('#topicId').html();
    var name = $(this).closest('header').find('input').val();
    $(this).closest('header').html('<h1 class="blue">'+name+'</h1><span class="fake-link white-grey topic-name-edit open fa fa-pencil"></span>');
    changeTopicNameService(topicId, name);
});

$("body").on("keypress", "input.topic-edit-name", function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        var topicId = $('#topicId').html();
        var name = $(this).closest('header').find('input').val();
        $(this).closest('header').html('<h1 class="blue">'+name+'</h1><span class="fake-link white-grey topic-name-edit open fa fa-pencil"></span>');
        changeTopicNameService(topicId, name);
    }
});
```

As you can see in my code, I call .on twice. Is there a possible method to join more .on calls ? 
If there is no solution, how can I use a existing var in a .on call ?
Greets

Answer (score 0):

you can define a global variable using `window` like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".topic-name-edit.close", function (event) {
    window.topicId = $('#topicId').html();
    window.name = $(this).closest('header').find('input').val();
    $(this).closest('header').html('<h1 class="blue">'+window.name+'</h1><span class="fake-link white-grey topic-name-edit open fa fa-pencil"></span>');
    changeTopicNameService(window.topicId, window.name);
});

$("body").on("keypress", "input.topic-edit-name", function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        window.topicId = $('#topicId').html();
        window.name = $(this).closest('header').find('input').val();
        $(this).closest('header').html('<h1 class="blue">'+window.name+'</h1><span class="fake-link white-grey topic-name-edit open fa fa-pencil"></span>');
        changeTopicNameService(window.topicId, window.name);
    }
});
```

also you can do this:

```
var topicId,
    name;
$("body").on("click", ".topic-name-edit.close", function (event) {
    topicId = $('#topicId').html();
    name = $(this).closest('header').find('input').val();
    $(this).closest('header').html('<h1 class="blue">'+name+'</h1><span class="fake-link white-grey topic-name-edit open fa fa-pencil"></span>');
    changeTopicNameService(topicId, name);
});

$("body").on("keypress", "input.topic-edit-name", function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        topicId = $('#topicId').html();
        name = $(this).closest('header').find('input').val();
        $(this).closest('header').html('<h1 class="blue">'+name+'</h1><span class="fake-link white-grey topic-name-edit open fa fa-pencil"></span>');
        changeTopicNameService(topicId, name);
    }
});
```